# Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $I=\langle x+1 \rangle$ an ideal of the ring $R[x]$. Show that $R[x]/I \cong R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $I=\langle x+1 \rangle$ an ideal of the ring $R[x]$. Show that $R[x]/I \cong R$.

Let $\varphi:R[x] \to R$ be the map $\varphi(p)=p(-1)$. Then $\ker(\varphi)=\{p \in R[x] \mid \varphi(p)=p(-1)=0\}$.

I know try to show that $\varphi$ is surjective and $\ker(\varphi)=I$. First if $p \in \ker(\varphi)$, then $p(x)=a_nx^n+ \dots + a_0$ and $p(-1)=0$. So $-1$ is a root of $p$ and thus $p(x)=(x+1)g(x) \in I$ for some $g \in R[x]$.

If $f \in I$, then $f(x)=(x+1)h(x)$ for $h \in R[x]$. Now $f(-1)=0$ which implies that $f \in \ker(\varphi)$.

I'm concerned wheter the $"\subset"$ of this is correct and how can I show that $\varphi$ is surjective?

Comment: To show it's surjective you can just use a constant polynomial

Comment: The first part is correct, and surjectivity comes from the constant polynomials.